# Pegar Apenas Número do Ranking do Registro em Uma Query

Tags: mysql

Tem como eu pegar o Ranking de um registro na tabela apenas com uma Query (mesmo que tenha uma Subquery) ?

Por exemplo, fiz isso abaixo:

```
SELECT
    a.id_concessionaria,
    a.avscore,
    @rank := @rank + 1 AS ranking
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            id_concessionaria,
            Avg(rating) AS AvScore
        FROM
            dealer_ratings
        GROUP BY
            id_concessionaria
    ) a
ORDER BY
    a.avscore DESC
```

E retorna:

```
12286   5.0000  1
11393   5.0000  2
11784   5.0000  3
11816   5.0000  4
12291   4.3333  5 --------------------- Essa aqui
12634   4.0000  6
19021   3.0000  7
10194   2.0000  8
```

Tem como eu pegar apenas o Rank do ID que eu quiser ?

Tentei fazer o `WHERE`, mas daí ele mostra o Rank como 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz um SELECT que pega esse resultado e daí nele você faz o WHERE, dessa forma:

```
SELECT b.ranking FROM (
    SELECT
        a.id_concessionaria,
        a.avscore,
        @rank := @rank + 1 AS ranking
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                id_concessionaria,
                Avg(rating) AS AvScore
            FROM
                dealer_ratings
            GROUP BY
                id_concessionaria
        ) a
    ORDER BY
        a.avscore DESC
) AS b WHERE b.id_concessionaria = '12291'
```

Comment: Obrigado, Mano. Era isso mesmo.

Comment: Blz brow! Até +